# What’s the difference between a statutory NSP and a notice to quit (NTQ) a periodic AST?

Tags: england-and-wales, notice

HA1988 defines assured shorthold tenancies (ASTs) based on there being certain factual conditions met. ASTs require notices seeking possession (NSPs) for landlords to end, namely either under s8 or s21. NSPs under both of those sections must be given in forms prescribed by the government.

Yet the NTQ (prescribed information) regulations 1988 seem to pertain to landlords who would seek to end a periodic AST. So what is the relationship between a NTQ and a prescribed-form NSP? Is one a subset of the other?

Comment: Please, please, please add context and information to your questions, including relevant links, and definitions of _all_ abbreviations. The question as originally written is likely to be incomprehensible to anyone not already familiar with the subject matter. (And as someone who _is_ familiar with the subject, I didn't recognise what "NSP" meant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted regulations don't apply to periodic assured tenancies, because Notices to Quit can't be used for such tenancies. From the [Housing Act 1988, section 5(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/5):

> the service by the landlord of a notice to quit is of no effect in relation to a periodic assured tenancy.

The notice period for a section 21, when used to end a periodic tenancy, is referenced in [section 21(4)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/21) of the Act, linking it to the notice period of a Notice to Quit - but making clear that NTQs still can't be used.

Comment: Ok, so this question confused me for a good long while. Can I ask how you identified and located the quoted section 5(1) of ha88 as the place in which to find the answer? Did you just know it was there from the top of your head, or was there more of a research process?

Comment: @Seekinganswers I remembered the quoted section from when I was learning about ASTs, as the introduction of ASTs fundamentally changed how landlords could end tenancies, by replacing an NTQ with a notice under s8 or s21.